# Selecting InfluxDB records with non-empty tags gets terribly slow

Tags: influxdb

I'm running Influx v1.3. I have a measurement with ~2+ million records within 1 month timespan and 10 tags within. Out of those, I'm interested in `user_id` and `article_id`.

I'm trying to extract number of events logged for specific `user_id` with non-empty `article_id`.

The query for selecting all user's events is blazingly fast:

```
select count(*) from pageviews where user_id = '92363';
```

The query for specific event for user and article is blazingly fast:

```
select * from pageviews where user_id = '92363' and article_id = '879729';
```

But when I try to add filter for non-empty (or empty) `article_id`, the query runs for tens of seconds.

```
select count(*) from pageviews where user_id = '92363' and article_id != '';
select count(*) from pageviews where user_id = '92363' and article_id !~ /.*/;
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or something I should configure within the database? This doesn't seem to be right. The number of user's events is <100, I'd literally went through them faster manually.

I'm currently running the default configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With queries using `!=` or `=~` the DB has to compare against each entry for that tag. If you have 2M entries, it will be slow. When using regular expressions (`=~`), even slower.

In short, no, you are not doing anything wrong. These types of queries are `O(n)` in influxdb where n is the number of rows you are comparing against.

I would suggest re-thinking your schema to avoid such queries. You could, for example, set an integer tag `has_article` that is either `0` or `1` indicating presence of an article. The query can then use `has_article = 1`.

Then again, whether the data set and data model is a good fit for influxdb is another question - the data set does not seem to be time series data.

InfluxDB is a specialised time series DB, not a general purpose data store.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the affirmation. I would expect it would optimize the query and check the tag against the filtered ~100 events, but it probably works differently than SQL databaze. The boolean workaround seems sufficient though.

I've also found that 1.4 will include `SHOW CARDINALITY` which can be used for tags, so I'll investiage that option too. Thanks a lot!